# Python: What is the BEST data structure to use in this scenario?

Tags: python, sockets, data-structures

I am trying to make a DNS Server and Client in python. Where Server will have stored data like:

```
qtsdatacenter.aws.com 128.64.3.2 A
ww.ibm.com 64.42.3.4 A
www.google.com 8.6.4.2 A
localhost - NS
```

Basically Hostname IPaddress Type.

What would be the best datastructure to implement that will make searching for queries and outputting referenced data easy.

For example: send a String saying `www.google.com` from  client, the server searches in its stored data table for the string match for hostname, returns in format
`www.google.com 8.6.4.2 A.`

Comment: This is a good use case for a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple like this. And use dictionary. Looks like your keys are going to be hashable and dictionaries possess O(1) average complexity. See this example:

```py
dct = {"www.google.com" : "www.google.com 8.6.4.2 A",
       "www.ibm.com" : " ww.ibm.com 64.42.3.4 A"}
```